# Media/file repository - asset autocomplete widget?

Tags: 7, files, media, ajax, entities

Does anyone know of a module which would install an autocomplete widget for file and image fields on admin-side?

The purpose of it would be to allow admin/editor to re-use a reference to an already uploaded file by typing its name. The widget would then auto-complete the path/reference based on the actual contents of directory where the asset is supposed to be uploaded. Otherwise, the file would have to be uploaded repeatedly.

Or, to rephrase the question: how do you folks solve such a media repository issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Media](http://drupal.org/project/media) module to store Images in a specific location,but you cant get the auto complete function with this module but you can select and reuse the old photos from the Image location.

The another good thing using this module is it is already integrated with the Ckeditor.